# Devise login form with form_inline in the header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, header

I am trying to have the Devise login form as a form_inline on my header.

the form_inline code is (link: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html):

```
  <form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

When I just copy the form over in the header it's looking good, but the login doesn't connect/communicate with devise.
![enter image description here][1]

I have tried to research about this, and tried different things to solve the problem, but haven't found anything to solve the problem.

Are there anyone who know how to solve this and get devise to work with form_inline in the header?

Answer (score 0):

Devise offers a generator to include its views directly into your application source code. You can do this and customize the views as you need it. Then Devise uses those views instead of its default views.

In brief:

```
# generate the views
# then you'll find them in the app/views/devise directory
rails generate devise:views
```

See further explanation in the [Devise readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views).